# Word for a real-time counter of something

Tags: synonyms

Is there any better word than just "counter" for a tool that counts/calculates something according to some rule and displays the result in a real time?

Examples of such tools:

- national debt clock
- number of people in the world (start with X and add f(X) every minute)
- average salary of our employees (they come and go, so it changes)
- my savings (I put away $10 a day; how much I already saved?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen such things (real time updates) on websites referred to as **tickers**.  i believe this comes from *stock tickers*, which predate the web, which are so named because they use *ticker tape*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_tape

I've also seen "scroller", although this, (perhaps like tickers), tend to refer to information which scrolls constantly across the screen, rather than a single number constantly updating in place.

Answer (score 1):

A "meter" is something that displays a count. An example is a car odometer, which displays the number of miles traveled. The counter of the number of units of fuel pumped into a car is also a meter.